# I can't run phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I'm using "CodeAnywhere" for my own project.

I had PHP, SQL, and PHPmyAdmin installed, but cannot access to PHPmyAdmin.

It keeps saying the following message:

> The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server

Can someone help me out?

Thank you :)

Comment: This is not how you ask the question. Read this before you ask question https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: My apology. This is my first time on stackoverflow and I won't have access to internet or even a computer 10 days from now. So I was quite desperate. Let me apologize for any fault I caused.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your Info page, you can see your Username and Password.
 Copy the link into the new tab of your browser and add `"/phpmyadmin"`
 at the end of the link to access phpMyAdmin.

It will look something like: `http://preview.xxxxxx.box.codeanywhere.com/phpmyadmin` or, in
 this example, `http://port-80.xxxxxx.box.codeanywhere.com/phpmyadmin`.
 For login use the "root" as Username, and leave the Password field
 empty:

Source: [docs.codeanywhere.com](https://docs.codeanywhere.com/#phpmyadmin)